# Is there an R function for changing a strange character date to POSIXct?

Tags: sql, r, lubridate

My date type looks like 7-Feb-20 (character) data, and I need to convert this into a data/time, so eventually I can use "As.Date() or as.POSIXct()" to move it into the SQL server as datetime. SQL server uses datetime as default when moving from R to SQL.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("7-Feb-20", format="%d-%b-%y")` returns a `POSIXt`-class object that, when passed to SQL Server, should be converted correctly to its `DATETIME` type.

Comment: Hi, So when I run the above code. I converts the whole column to N/A.

Comment: It works on as much sample data as you've provided. Perhaps you can demonstrate cases where it does not work? (This includes providing representative sample data -- some that work, some that don't work -- as well as the code you are using and what you think its output *should* be.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `as.Date()` function will convert character data into a date format.

You can specify the input format by using the `format =` argument.

In this case, it looks like your format is `%d-%b-%y`

- `%d` will give you day
- `%b` will give you abbreviated month name (compare with `%B`, which gives full month name)
- `%y` will give you two-digit year.

You will also need to include the hyphen in your format.